# What is 1 transaction in Parse.com?

Tags: android, json, database, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com as a database for my app. Right now I'm using the free version which claims that you get 1 million transactions per month. What is considered 1 transaction? So far I have 43 rows in my table. Is this 43 transactions? Also, if I import a large amount of data from a file, is that considered only one transaction?

Comment: IMO - each call to the api is = "transaction"

Comment: I think Robert is right.  Keep in mind there are all kinds of other limitations too - like only about 2000 transactions in a minute before you're cut off.  Cloud code can run for only a few seconds before it gets terminated.  Probably some others.

Answer (score 0):

With the [new pricing](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/parse-pricing-now-cheaper-and-simpler/) model, you can potentially make 77.76 million calls per month (or 30 req/s). The calls include:

- Any kind of request to Parse (including queries, saves, logins and others). Batch operation does not reduce the requests.
- Every time you serve a file like image that is stored on Parse, it's counted a request.
- Website hosting files are also counted as requests

Note that you can only request maximum of 1800 requests per minute. If you make more, you will get error.

I have summarized things from Parse's [Pricing FAQ](https://www.parse.com/plans/faq/). Many things you wanna know may be listed there.